# Check whether window.onerror is availale or not

Tags: javascript, logging, developer-tools

In my javascript logging framework,I am catching unhandled exceptions through window.onerror handler.

How could I check for whether window.onerror is available or not.since in few browsers it would not recognize window.onerror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with :

```
if(typeof window.onerror === 'undefined'){
// you can't use window.onerror
}else{
//you can
}
```

Check out the MDN docs for a headstart on how you might override or create some kind of polyfill that would work cross browser:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.onerror